# netcat listening on nexus 4 doesn't seem to respond

Tags: networking, nexus-4, command-line

I have a Nexus 4 on my wifi network along with a laptop. I would like to establish a connection using netcat from my laptop to my phone.

On my phone, I can run `uname -a | nc <LAPTOP IP> <PORT>`, on my laptop, I can receive it by running `nc -l <PORT>`, and I can see the output on my laptop.

However, when I run `nc -l <PORT>` on my phone, when I send messages using netcat on my laptop, nothing appears to happen.

Is there a firewall on Android blocking incoming connections?

Comment: What port are you actually trying to listen on?

Comment: @DanHulme I tried 4350 and 4242